# Group long object of dates, into object of months

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, object

I have a very long object of dates, which pairs a date with a price/number.  For example:

```
let obj = {
"2022-09-17": 45,
"2022-09-18": 35,
"2022-09-19": 34,
"2022-09-20": 26,
"2022-09-21": 25,
"2022-09-22": 33,
"2022-09-23": 56,
"2022-09-24": 39,
"2022-09-25": 49,
"2022-09-26": 25,
"2022-09-27": 25,
"2022-09-28": 25,
"2022-09-29": 33,
"2022-09-30": 42,
"2022-10-01": 28,
"2022-10-02": 38,
"2022-10-03": 35,
"2022-10-04": 25,
"2022-10-05": 25,
"2022-10-06": 31
}
```

What is the best way to regroup this object as an array of months, which correlate to the dates and contain the key/values?

Eg - like this screenshot:

[image]

I want to group the key/value pair by months, so I can later, then loop through all months, to find the lowest price of each month.

But first, I wanted to figure out the best way to break up this object, in months?

Thanks,

Comment: For starters it should be an object, not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As often, [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is a good solution here

```
let object = {
  "2022-09-17": 45,
  "2022-09-18": 35,
  "2022-09-19": 34,
  "2022-09-20": 26,
  "2022-09-21": 25,
  "2022-09-22": 33,
  "2022-09-23": 56,
  "2022-09-24": 39,
  "2022-09-25": 49,
  "2022-09-26": 25,
  "2022-09-27": 25,
  "2022-09-28": 25,
  "2022-09-29": 33,
  "2022-09-30": 42,
  "2022-10-01": 28,
  "2022-10-02": 38,
  "2022-10-03": 35,
  "2022-10-04": 25,
  "2022-10-05": 25,
  "2022-10-06": 31
}

const objectMonth = Object
  .keys(object)
  .reduce((acc, key) => {
    const date = new Date(key)
    const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })
    acc[month] = acc[month] || []
    acc[month].push({
      date: key,
      price: object[key]
    })
    return acc
  }, {})

console.log(objectMonth)
```

Comment: Be aware that the locale string depends on the settings of the environment and that the result may differ depending on machine/clients where it is executed. So based on the usecase, it might be better to assign a static locale like `en-GB` instead of `default`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

**Logic**

- Loop through the entries in object
- Split the date into year, month and date.
- Get the month name with some logic.
- Reduce this array of entries in the object.

```js
let obj = {
  "2022-09-17": 45,
  "2022-09-18": 35,
  "2022-09-19": 34,
  "2022-09-20": 26,
  "2022-09-21": 25,
  "2022-09-22": 33,
  "2022-09-23": 56,
  "2022-09-24": 39,
  "2022-09-25": 49,
  "2022-09-26": 25,
  "2022-09-27": 25,
  "2022-09-28": 25,
  "2022-09-29": 33,
  "2022-09-30": 42,
  "2022-10-01": 28,
  "2022-10-02": 38,
  "2022-10-03": 35,
  "2022-10-04": 25,
  "2022-10-05": 25,
  "2022-10-06": 31,
};
const months = [
  "january",
  "february",
  "march",
  "april",
  "may",
  "june",
  "july",
  "august",
  "september",
  "october",
  "november",
  "december",
];
const splittedData = Object.entries(obj).reduce(
  (acc, [dateStr, value]) => {
    const [year, month, date] = dateStr.split("-");
    if (!acc[months[+month - 1]]) {
      acc[months[+month - 1]] = [];
    }
    acc[months[+month - 1]].push({ [dateStr]: value });
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);
console.log(splittedData);
```

Comment: Hi Ji ash and Nitheesh, thanks so much for your solutions! I was kinda going a bit crazy breaking down the approach.  But appreciate both the approaches here, so will break down both of them.  Thank you! And thanks Christopher for the caution on the locale.

Comment: I didn't realise you could chain .reduce() onto object.keys() - interesting..

Comment: Everything is possible. `object.keys()` return an array with which you can run `Array.reduce()`. This can be done in single shot